# Android webview pinch zoom local image

Tags: android, webview, zooming, local, pinch

Hey I'm trying to get pinch to zoom working on a Webview of my app but cant, it just displays the image really zoomed in (probably displaying it 100%)

here is how i got the webview to work.

In the activity I added

```
 WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sitemap.png");
```

The image is in the assets folder and is named sitemap.png

The layout xml I used for the webview is

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

I have not added anything else to the code. Can you tell me what isnt working, as say it displays the picture perfectly but i cant pinch zoom, what is the easiest way to solve this as i am nooby

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In API 3, you can use [setBuiltInZoomControls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29):

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

**See Also:**
[Disable pinch zoom in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024140/disable-pinch-zoom-in-webview)

Comment: can you elaborate more for me please spent last 2 hours trying to get it working and still cant

Comment: `mWebView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

Comment: `mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`


In case some people don't know about getSettings()