# Why does pinch-to-zoom not work in my Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an activity with a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <include  layout="@layout/window_title" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how I'm configuring it:

```
    // Enable JavaScript.
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Settings so page loads zoomed-out all the way.
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Here's the version setting from my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I'm trying to load this page in the WebView:

```
https://new.livestream.com/lcboise
```

The page loads just fine, but I can't pinch to zoom. I've tried different combinations of the WebView settings (above, including others not listed) but it just won't zoom.

Observations:

1) Loading up a different page I'm using (https://lcboise.infellowship.com/UserLogin) in the EXACT same WebView allows me to zoom.

2) My main test device, where is DOES NOT work, is a HTC One running v4.4.3 of Android.

3) I can load, and zoom, the livestream page on an older test device I'm using that's running v2.3.3 of Android.

Is it possible that something in the page itself is breaking the WebView running on the HTC One? If so, any guesses as to might be doing it?

Update [SOLUTION]:

Here is what I had to add to my WebView to get pinch-to-zoom to work:

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String javascript="javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0');";
            view.loadUrl(javascript);
        }
    });
```

Comment: plus one for the question..

Comment: Thanks for the question and the solution! Your snippet can actually enable the webview zoom by fingers, however it adds an additional zoom in/out button besides the webview native ones. Do you know any way to disable them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the page you linked has the following viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

The page that works has a different viewport meta tag. The `maximum-scale` bit is telling the WebView to not allow zooming in more than the specified amount.

The site should also be broken in any modern mobile browser. Setting maximum-scale to a low value like that is not very "mobile friendly" so it might just be a bug on the site. Have you tried contacting the owner, maybe they can fix it server-side?

There is not a whole lot you can do in the WebView that will not result in other sites rendering incorrectly. You could try injecting JavaScript to fix up the page by [changing the meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly) as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up having to inject some Javascript into the page just like you said. See my update above to view the exact code I put in it.

Comment: Your answer helped me, plus 1

Answer (score 11):

Add these two lines to enable pinch to zoom in webview

```
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this suggestion?

```
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

See [Disable pinch zoom in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024140/disable-pinch-zoom-in-webview)

Note the link is in regards for disabling zoom. But perhaps your zoom is being disabled by default as some users suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this does not work. Like I said above, I'm a bit perplexed why I can load a different page in the exact WebView in the exact Activity and it zooms just fine. At first glance, this would seem to implicate the web page itself as the source of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

On my issue, I succeed with above JavaScript injection due to viewport restrictions. Somehow **onPageFinished** didn't worked in my case but **onLoadResource** did the trick.

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName(\"viewport\")[0].setAttribute(\"content\", \"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes\");");
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
}
```

Comment: I have been finding the solution to this problem for a very long time! I had given up but just now came across this answer and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

```
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Zoom:

```
webSettings.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

For Disable:

```
webSettings.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow zoom at Android WebView the only settings needed are:

1. webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
2. webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
3. Make sure that HTML header `viewport` has proper values;
4. If you are changing the settings after load, make sure **call from UIThread**;